# Numerical Issues with DDE from SEIRU$\delta$ model

Tags: matlab, ode, dde

I'm new in this community. I moved this question from Math community. I'm reading the following article

[Article Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340968262_A_COVID-19_epidemic_model_with_latency_period)

and my target is to replicate the results for a project.

- SEIRU Model: I obtained very nice results though I not used article data but my data. Here is the evolution image I obtained playing around with the parameters.

[image: SEIRU Results]

- SEIRU$\delta$ Model: Started with the same parameters values as the SEIRU Model. Cannot obtain a nice picture. The model has the same behaviour as the standard one, but I think there are some initial conditions errors. For small $\delta$ it is completely out of scale. To obtain the same numbers as the SEIRU I must use $\delta=81.5$ which is a very big number. Moreover with that $\delta$ I obtain a reproduction number $\mathcal{R}_0=2.6626e+05$ which again is impressive and not correct.

[[image: SEIRU<span class=]$\delta$ Results" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RV9i.jpg)

Never done numerical simulations with DDE. Maybe I did not manage very well the DDE system. I wrote my code in MATLAB, now I share it with you. Here is the links.

- [SEIRU Code Link](https://codeshare.io/5glV6B)
- [SEIRU$\delta$ Code Link](https://codeshare.io/aYQxWL)

In the code there isn't the real data, only the fitted parameters the models need. Moreover the pictures you will see launching the code correspond to the picture here. I would say the target is to obtain the same results using the same fitted parameters. In this case they are $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$, $\chi_3=1$ is fixed. Hope you can understand the code. Some easiest ways to manage DDE? Hope some of you could help me. Thanks in advance.